# convert a htaccess rule to nginx conf

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

i must convert some htaccess rules for nginx. for missing immages the shopsystem look in the image folder to crate small images on the fly. but the shopsystem only had infos for apache webserver .... maybe someone can help me out here??

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/product_images/)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (\.jpe?g|\.gif|\.png)$ pt_getimg.php
```

Can someone help me? It must be the first rewrite rule.

My conf file at the moment:

```
server {
        server_tokens   off;
        listen          80;
        server_name     XXXXXXX.de;
        access_log      /var/log/nginx/MUH.XXXXXXX.de.access.log;
        error_log       /var/log/nginx/MUH.XXXXXXX.de.error.log error;

        rewrite         ^(.*)           http://www.XXXXXXX.de$1 permanent;
}

server {
        server_tokens   off;
        listen          80;
        server_name     www.XXXXXXX.de;
        access_log      /var/log/nginx/XXXXXXX.de.access.log;
        error_log       /var/log/nginx/XXXXXXX.de.error.log error;

        root            /var/www/XXXXXXX.de;
        index           index.php index.html index.htm;
        autoindex       off;

        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

    location ~* /XXXXXXX-backup {
        auth_basic              "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file    /etc/nginx/htpasswd.XXXXXXX;

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass                    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_split_path_info         ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors        on;
                include                         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }


        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg|ttf)$ {
                expires max;
                #log_not_found off;
        }

        if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite /(.*/)?Blog/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+).html.* /blog.php?blog_cat=$2&blog_item=$3 last;
    rewrite /(.*/)?Blog/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?.* /blog.php?blog_cat=$2 last;
    rewrite /(.*/)?Blog/ /blog.php last;
    rewrite /(.*/)?info/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+).html.* /shop_content.php?gm_boosted_content=$2&$args last;
    rewrite /(.*/)?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+).html /product_info.php?gm_boosted_product=$2&$args last;
    rewrite /(.*/)?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?.* /index.php?gm_boosted_category=$2&$args last;
    rewrite /(.*/)?Blog/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?.* /blog.php?blog_cat=$2 last;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass                    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_split_path_info         ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors        on;
                include                         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }

}
```

Sorry for my bad english, hope you can read and understand it. thank you.

Comment: Never use `if`: http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil

Comment: why never use ?
i am new in nginx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is often done with Rewrite in Apache is done with location matches in nginx:

```
location /product_images/ {
    try_files $uri @get_img;
}

location @get_img {
    rewrite ^.*$ /product_images/pt_getimg.php;
}
```